# How do I print 1 to n in a listbox using recursion in C#?

Tags: c#, recursion, listbox

I am trying to write a program that uses recursion to cycle through a given value and print it in order into a listbox. The output is supposed to look like this when I use 5 for n:

1 2 3 4 5

However, I cannot figure out a way to make my program work, and any other sources I get only use console functions.

Down below is the code I have so far. I would appreciate any help I can get with this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int n;
    n = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    int print = Print(1, n);
    listBox1.Items.Add(print);
}
       
private static int Print(int order, int n)
{
    if (n < 1)
    {
        return order;
    }
    n--;
    return Print(order + 1, n);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not able to test this out right now, but I hope I have made the concept clear.
Something like this should do the work:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int n;
    n = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    PrintToListBox(listBox1, 1, n);
}
    
private static void PrintToListBox(ListBox listBox, int frm, int to)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(frm);
    if (frm + 1 <= to)
    {
        PrintToListBox(listBox1, frm + 1, n);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you lorenzo, this is just what I needed

Answer (score 0):

I would write it as:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    PrintToListBox(listBox1, 1, 5);
}

private void PrintToListBox(ListBox lb, int n, int max)
{
    if (n <= max)
    {
        lb.Items.Add(n);
        PrintToListBox(lb, n+1, max);
    }
}
```